# update data in multimodel form in a single page

Tags: php, yii

I followed [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/) for Yii multimodel and now I can insert data successfully in two different models. But my problem is now how can I update the data?How to render the both models in a single page for update process.The document provided in that link is only for insert data.So how to update data in that?

Comment: can you tell me at which line the error occurs(the code in the line)?, you should be able to see that in the error information that would be displayed. where do you get that "Undefined variable: member" error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yii insert and Update follows nearly same syntax. So it should be possible to use same code with little modifications. try this

```
$this->render('update', array(
    'a'=>$a,
    'b'=>$b,
));
```

the partial view used for update and insert views is a single file `_form.php`. so it should render the update view properly.

Comment: Nope..I used that method and it is showing error like this Undefined variable: member

Comment: @Jagdish did you modify your 'update' view file also? i.e update.php